# How do you set var=/? in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

```
C:\>set g=/?

C:\>echo %g%
Displays messages, or turns command-echoing on or off.

  ECHO [ON | OFF]
  ECHO [message]

Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting.

C:\>
```

if I do set g="/?"  then echo %g% then it includes quotes.

I just want /? without quotes, when I do echo %g% it should just say /?

No greater reason. But it's what I want. Hopefully is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the text to be displayed as output, even if it is the word `ON`, the word `OFF`, or an option sequence, use the infamous *echo dot* trick.  Instead of the `echo` command, use the `echo.` command.

```
C:\>set g=/?

C:\>echo. %G%
 /?

C:\>echo. on
 on

C:\>echo.%G%
/?

C:\>
```

Notice the odd behaviour of `echo.` with respect to separating whitespace, and with respect to how the command-line parser detects the end of the command name.  If you have [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccle_cmd_replacement.html), you can of course still use this rather dubious syntax, which has its roots in the MS-DOS `COMMAND` where several punctuation characters in addition to whitespace were "termination" characters, but it's far better to use the more regular native syntax of TCC, not least because it retains ordinary whitespace as the separator between command name and command tail:

```
[C:\]set g=/?

[C:\]echo ``%G%
/?

[C:\]
```

TCC's native syntax will not prevent `on` and `off` from being recognized specially, however.  For that you still need the `echo.` command.

Comment: In CMD, `echo(` may be necessary sometimes - [someone has done a test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181212/windows-in-batch-file-write-multiple-lines-to-text-file/5181213#comment-5821211), and `echo.%var%` may collide with a filename, and so on...

Comment: @grawity interesting link, so echo.%var% collides if you have a file called echo in that dir! But how would you do echo %bb% if you had a variable called bb and you didn't want it to display the contents of bb? but just literally %bb%. I see echo.%bb% or echo/%bb% or echo %bb% all have the issue.

Comment: @barlop: Try `echo ^%bb^%` and `echo %%bb%%`, one of them should work.

Comment: @gravvity what about !bb!   ?

Comment: @barlop echo ^^!bb^!  don't know the mechanics of why escaping the first exclamation mark once didn't do it but twice did, but anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's working as is. :)

When you set "g" to be "/?" and then type `echo %g%` you are actually typing `echo /?`, which (as it should) gives you the help on echo that you are seeing ("Displays messages, or turns command-echoing on or off...").

If you type `echo test%g%` you'll get `test/?` returned.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `set g=/?` is correct.  The problem is that /? means something special to cmd.exe.  It means show help for the command.  For example try `dir /?`. Or in your case `echo /?`.

Run `set g` and you will see that g is indeed set to /?

So when you run `echo %g%` you are really running `echo /?` which tells cmd.exe to print the help message.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the '`/`' - so try:

```
C:\>set g=\/?
```

Comment: you didn't test that, did you. Try echo %b% after. And anyhow, the  escape character in cmd is ^, and notice set g=^/? is the same as set g=/?