# How this windows command works: echo %path:;=&echo.%

Tags: windows, command-line

Searching for a solution to print pathes inside `path` variable in windows Command-Line i came to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884892/print-windows-path-with-every-entry-on-new-line) solution. the answer is this command:

```
echo %path:;=&echo.%
```

now i wonder how this works.

Comment: [Warning: `echo.` may not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files#comment51324419_132811).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's an interesting solution that I've never seen before. Let me try to explain:

1. To print the entire path, use `echo %path%`. This will print all directories on a single line separated with semicolons (`;`)
2. To search / replace a string in a variable, use `%path:a=b%` which will replace all `a` characters with `b`
3. `echo.` is used to print a newline
4. `&` is used to separate commands, e.g. `echo line1&echo line2` will print two lines
5. In effect, semicolons in the path are replaced with a *command* to print a newline. Or maybe it is interpreted as 'replace `;` with nothing, *and then*, print a newline'. I can't find any documentation on this, so it's just my interpretation. Frankly, I didn't even know that was possible, but there you go. **UPDATE** My interpretation of this step seems to be off, and is better explained by [wizzwizz4](https://superuser.com/a/1369202/94931).

Comment: what is %% signs used for, can;t we tell `echo path`? are %% used for variables?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, those are used to get the value of a variable. For instance: `set greeting=Hello` and then `echo %greeting%`. Confusingly, `PATH` happens to be both a command and a variable, so typing the command `path`, or `echo %path%` will have the same result.

Comment: what this syntax is called? is it regex? or something used in windows CMD only

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a name for this, it is just the way variables work in DOS. Other languages, such as bash, use `$PATH` for instance.

Comment: This is not regex, its cmd only. That's why I removed the regex tag from the question. The correct naming would be Command Line Syntax.

Comment: it's the [replace syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: This is nothing to do with DOS, Berend; and `echo.` is not "the command to print a newline".  This is _Microsoft's command interpreter_ for Windows NT, `cmd`; and the `echo.` is simply the command to print a path element _ensuring that if the path element is empty it does not switch to the **other** functionality of `echo`_.  The first `echo` really should be an `echo.` too.

Comment: @JdeBP It's clear to me that in this example `echo.` is being used to add newlines between path elements. @berend was explaining its purpose in the example, not its syntax definition. "the command to print a path element" is also not the syntax definition of `echo.`. Your explanation is a combination of what `.` does in conjunction with `echo` and what `echo.` is being used to accomplish in this case. While your sentence tells me that you understand the interpreter syntax, it wouldn't have taught me anything had I been unfamiliar with the concepts.

Answer (score 35):

This is using command-line variable substitution. `%path:;=&echo.%` means "`%path%`, but replace all `;`s with `&echo.`". This means that, with `set path=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows\;;C:\Python37;`:

```
echo %path:;=&echo.%
```

becomes:

```
echo C:\Windows\System32&echo.C:\Windows\&echo.&echo.C:\Python37&echo.
```

Since `&` is a command separator, this is equivalent to:

```
echo C:\Windows\System32
echo.C:\Windows\
echo.
echo.C:\Python37
echo.
```

Due to quirks of DOS Batch, `echo.` is identical to `echo` *except* when there's nothing after it. If that's the case, it simply prints nothing, instead of telling you whether `ECHO` is on or off. This will make the output:

```
C:\Users\wizzwizz4> echo %path:;&echo.%
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Windows\

C:\Python37

C:\Users\wizzwizz4>
```

Really, it should be `echo.%path:;=&echo.%` to account for the case where `%PATH%` starts with a `;`, but this command is pretty clever anyway.

---

Getting into detailed detalias, *really* `echo(` should be used instead of `echo.`. This is because `echo.` can have problems when you've got a file called `echo`, and is slow because it has to check the disk (`%CD%` and I think also all of `%PATH%`) every time it runs. (I don't have a copy of Windows so I can't check it myself; is it just `%CD%` or anywhere in the `%PATH%` that the presence of the `echo` file will affect `echo.`, and what does it do?)

Comment: This is long-standing behaviour of Microsoft/IBM command interpreters across several operating systems, and is not specific to batch scripts.  As I noted at https://superuser.com/a/310157/38062 years ago, there are several punctuation characters in addition to whitespace that count as command-name termination characters.

Comment: @JdeBP I think one of the more efficient ones is `echo)`, but I don't really remember. ;-(

Comment: `echo.` is the one that people used to circulate the most, years ago.  It is the one in many books.  Efficiency is not the problem.  Wacky behaviour when various files happen to exist is.  When I wrote a 32-bit replacement for the 16-bit `cmd` in OS/2, breaking command names at these punctuation characters and this highly irregular parsing behaviour is one of the things that I deliberately did not duplicate, and which I put on the documented list of differences.  I made an external `echodot` command instead, which one could alias as `echo.` as desired.

Comment: @JdeBP That sounds really interesting! Do you think you could [document some of that](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: If you follow various comment links you end up at a third-party forum message claming that `echo(` is the only safe version.

Comment: @Neil If you can find it, check out the old Stack Overflow Documentation page on Batch Files, specifically the `ECHO` section. I'm certain I remember editing around an explanation as to _why_ `echo(` was better.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter works in 2 consecutive passes. Pass 1 performs all parameter substitutions.
But a little-documented feature of parameter substitution is that for each individual parameter a secondary substitution is instructed with the syntax :STRING1=STRING2 after the parameter name. This is repeated multiple times if STRING1 appears more than once.
Only then does Pass 2 interpret the line for execution. Try this for demystification:

echo %path:WINDOWS=UNIX%